# Need a way to know if at least 1 check box is checked on my form with jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Hello I have the following function that is NOT working at the moment..

What I need is to show some DIVs if at least 1 checkbox is checked in my form, if no checkboxes are checked those Divs stay hidden. Also this should be fired Everytime based on what the user does, and not only the first time...How can I do it?

Thanks

```
function Checkbox() {
if($("#tuitting_form input:checkbox:checked").length > 0){
$("#send_message").show();
$("#remove_accounts").show();
}else{
$("#send_message").fadeOut();
$("#remove_accounts").fadeOut();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems to work for me.  Just add it to the changed event listener for checkboxes.  See [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/JB9cv/1).

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function(){
    if($("input:checkbox:checked").length > 0){
        $("#send_message").show();
        $("#remove_accounts").show();
    }else{
        $("#send_message").fadeOut();
        $("#remove_accounts").fadeOut();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){

   $("#tuitting_form input:checkbox").change(function(){
    if($("#tuitting_form input:checkbox:checked").length > 0){   
      $("#send_message").show(); 
      $("#remove_accounts").show();
    }else{
      $("#send_message").fadeOut();
      $("#remove_accounts").fadeOut();
    }
   }

});
```